# How to break query into smaller queries

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a PHP that goes through a large table in DB, then when I get the results I put them into CSV. But the table keeps growing and now I got error that allowed memory size is exhausted.

```
 SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table
```

And due to the size of table I can not put it into csv. How could I reduce the size of this query? Should I use LIMIT and then just put it into 2 halves?

Comment: you should use array_chunk

Comment: Yes, using `LIMIT` sounds like the better solution here. The alternative would be to remove some columns, which would remove some informations for the sheet. The rows are indepentant from each other, while the columns are describing a row togehter.

Comment: It is a common practice to limit the maximum number of records that can be exported due to performance issues, use `LIMIT` in your query. If you need to export the whole table, then make multiple queries using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`

Comment: No. Show the PHP code. You are probably trying to load everything into memory at once, instead of processing the result line by line.

Comment: try ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); I hope it will work for you..

Comment: IMHO just changing the memory limit to maximum is a bad idea.  It'll work for a while longer and then fail again.  Main thing is to fix the original code not just hope the problem goes aay.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing to CSV, use fopen/fwrite to keep a stream instead of trying to concat to a string (which will cause out of memory fast if it's large), for the database query itself, using the _fetch_array() you can keep the result active on the server whilst only retrieving row by row from PHP.

This should keep the memory usage quite low.